# Accessing a database field via current_user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm fairly new to Ruby AND Ruby on Rails, so please bear with me...

I'm designing an e-learning and I want the database to track a user's progress. Users can log in, edit their profile etc; That all works fine.

I've added a new field to the database, via

```
rails generate migration add_field_name_to_users example_field_name:int
rake db:migrate
```

My problem is how to access that field value and display it on screen. How, or WHERE do I declare it? I was assuming it should go in my user.rb model, but just including it there won't ensure it's set at 0 when a user first signs up. And it can't just be a local variable because it's got to be stored on the database. Also, how do even I access the value?
I've tried:

```
<p>Progress: <%= current_user.example_field_name %>/10</p>
```

in the appropriate view, but that throws an

```
undefined method `example_field_name' for #<User:0x4bc6738>
```

error. I do have access to current_user (that, on its own doesn't throw an error), but I don't know how to access the new field value.

Any help, much appreciated.

**EDIT**

As requested, here's the last migration file:

```
class AddLeadershipStylesProgressToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :leadership_syles_progress, :int
  end
end
```

And yes, I've just realised that I missed a 't' in 'styles'. When I use current_user.leadership_syles_progress it doesn't output anything, but I'm betting that's because no value has been set.
SO:

How do I set the value when a user signs up the first time?

Sorry for the slight change in question direction - I hope that's OK.

Comment: Do you use `Devise` gem?

Comment: Yes, the devise gem is used.

Comment: Do you tried test new field in `rails console`? If you run `User.last` new field available in returned object?

Comment: No, I haven't. Thanks for the suggestion. How would I do that?

Comment: please post last migration file. (in `db/migrate/****_ add_field_name_to_users.rb`)

Comment: If your migration is correct, you should have the field when you do a `User.last.attributes.keys` in console.

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm Yes, the field I added is listed there

Comment: you want add default column value or set value on create?

Comment: I'd like to set the value on user profile creation.

Answer (score 1):

**Helper**

The [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) object is simply a helper which gives you the ability to invoke the signed in user's `User` object. Nothing more than this

By virtue of this, you need to appreciate that when you call `current_user`, it's basically going to be using exactly the same values / variables that you'll get when you call the standard `User` objects. As such, `example_field_name` *should* be available when you wish to call it

In short, it will work for you *if* you have done everything correctly

--

**Migration**

The problems you may have include:

> 1. The migration did not fire properly
> 2. Your `field_name` conflicts with some reserved method names in rails (unlikely)
> 3. Your syntax is wrong

Judging from the code you've provided, I'd rule out the syntax being incorrect, and that your `field_name` is reserved in Rails. Instead, I'd focus on the migration, and more specifically, how that migration was adding the various columns to your db.

I generally stay clear of the "generated" migrations - I like to maintain my code manually. As such, here's what I'd do:

```
> $ rails g migration NewField

#db/migrate/new_field_...rb
class NewField < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change 
      add_column :users, :your_field, :integer
   end
end

> $ rake db:migrate
```

You'll then be able to validate this by using the Rails console:

```
> $ rails c
> $ users = User.all
> $ [output of users with all attributes]
```

---

**Update**

If you want to set the extra field when you create a user, you'll generally want to use the `before_create` callback in your model. This will create a *default* value, which you can then change as you wish:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_field

   private

   def set_field
      self.field = "your value"
   end
end
```

If you'd like to set the param when you use Devise, you'll want to add the field to your form, then ensure the [Devise params hash](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) permits the value to be submitted to your model:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :your_field
  end
end
```

--

**Fix**

For clarity, this is what worked for the OP in the end:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_field

   private

   def set_field
      self.field = "your value"
   end
end
```

Comment: I understand that current_user is an instance of class User. What I need to know is how to SET a particular database field when a user signs up. I have run the console checks you suggest and the new field is there on each instance. What do you suggest for SETTING the value on sign up?

Comment: Okay - I thought you wanted to know about how to call the `current_user` object. Let me update the answer for you

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have tried exactly what you suggest (in the first section of code) and checked, again, User.all in rails console and the field is present but set to nil, despite it being set to 5 in the set_field user method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you create a new object to test this? The `before_create` action only works when you create a new object

Comment: Yes. I signed up as a new user.

Comment: Hmm okay, and had the `before_create` method in there?

Comment: Yes. I've called it 'set_progress_vars' in both places, but otherwise it's identical.

Comment: Okay, can you try setting in the console? By typing `rails c` then trying `User.create(name: "test")` or similar?

Comment: I can set it via rails console. ie; z = User.find(26) < this is the :id of the record   z.field_name = 9     z.save

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61472/discussion-between-moosefetcher-and-rich-peck).

Comment: You can specify default value in the migration, no? And retroactively update old users in the same migration (or another)

Comment: Yes that would work - you must remember that getting to a working solution was pretty difficult